# self signed certificate throwing "RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding" error

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl, rsa, x509

My domain uses a self signed certificate created like this:

```
$ ISSUER="/C=EN/L=City/O=ORG"
$ SUBJECT="/C=EN/L=City/O=ORG/CN=myserver.com"
$ SAN="DNS:myserver.com"
$ openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout issuer.key -x509 -out issuer.crt  -days 3650 -nodes -subj "$ISSUER"
$ openssl req -new -out subject.csr -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout subject.key -days 3650 -nodes -subj "$SUBJECT"
$ echo "subjectAltName=$SAN" > subject.ext
$ openssl x509 -in subject.csr -req -out subject.crt -extfile subject.ext -CA issuer.crt -CAkey issuer.key -CAcreateserial -days 3650
$ cp issuer.crt myserver.crt
$ cp subject.key myserver.key
$ cat subject.crt issuer.crt > certbundle.pem
```

My nginx webserver ssl config:

```
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /keys/certbundle.pem;   
        ssl_certificate_key /keys/myserver.key;
```

If I add the certificate myserver.crt to `/etc/ssl/certs/` of my client machine, run `openssl rehash` on it and then try to download something from my domain via curl `curl --capath /etc/ssl/certs/ https://myserver.com/file.txt` I get

```
curl: (35) error:0407008A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding
```

Why is it throwing this error? What am I doing wrong when generating the keys and certificates?

Edit:

Running `curl --cacert certs/domain.crt https://my.server.com/file.txt --output file.txt` works fine. File is downloaded. When I run `openssl rehash` on my folder and then use `curl --capath folder/` the same rsa padding error reappears

Comment: What happens if you use `curl --cacerts </path/to/the/single/root> https://my.server.com/file.txt` ?  The `--cacerts` point to a file containing a bundle of one or more root CA certs.  This allows you to check whether the rehash failed or the root CA cert is suspect.

Comment: `curl --cacert certs/domain.crt https://my.server.com/file.txt --output file.txt` worked perfectly, no error messages. I run `openssl rehash` on my certs/ folder and then curl with --capath and the same rsa padding error happens.

Comment: Are you sure the way you specify subjectAlternativeName works? On recent OpenSSL versions there are easier ways to specify SAN: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/183973/1204 Also the validity time of your leaf cert is very high (10 years). Modern browsers don't accept this anymore. Use a maximum of ~365 days for the leaf cert.

Comment: @Robert I think `-extfile` is not an issue, I just tested the content of my pem and `root@test:~/cert# openssl x509 -noout -ext subjectAltName -in certbundle.pem 
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
    DNS:myserver.com` . I am also not using a browser here just command line commands and openssl. Openssl should throw an error if this length is not allowed, right?

Comment: Why are you running `openssl rehash`?  Most distros provide the `ca-certificates` package which includes the `update-ca-certificates` command which looks after updating the trust-store.  Normally, drop the new root certificate in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` on Debian/Ubuntu and run `update-ca-certificates`.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to issue an SSL certificate by a self-created CA to use it for web development on localhost and was getting the same error. I tried to create a working SSL certificate multiple times, but always had this error `error:0407008A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding`, and I had multiple certificate authorities with the same CN registered in my operating system's trust source (`/etc/ca-certificates/trust-source` on manjaro):

```
me@host /e/c/trust-source> ls -al
total 116
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Sep 26 02:47 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May  8  2019 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 25 09:46 anchors/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 10  2018 blocklist/
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2685 Sep 25 10:02 test.com.1.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2564 Sep 25 10:50 test.com.10.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2560 Sep 25 10:54 test.com.11.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2564 Sep 25 11:05 test.com.12.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2692 Sep 25 11:08 test.com.13.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2692 Sep 25 11:09 test.com.14.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2678 Sep 25 11:09 test.com.15.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2692 Sep 25 11:16 test.com.16.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2698 Sep 25 11:16 test.com.17.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2696 Sep 25 12:06 test.com.18.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2700 Sep 26 01:06 test.com.19.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2686 Sep 25 10:11 test.com.2.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2687 Sep 26 02:34 test.com.20.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2697 Sep 26 01:24 test.com.21.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2698 Sep 25 10:25 test.com.3.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2567 Sep 25 10:31 test.com.4.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2574 Sep 25 10:31 test.com.5.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2560 Sep 25 10:32 test.com.6.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2580 Sep 25 10:33 test.com.7.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2560 Sep 25 10:33 test.com.8.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2560 Sep 25 10:42 test.com.9.p11-kit
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2685 Sep 26 02:47 test.com.p11-kit
```

How I solved the problem: I deleted all these "duplicates" and ran `update-ca-trust` to regenerate the list of CAs trusted by my system. Then imported my self-created CA once, generated an SSL certificate against it and used the crt and key in my web server - finally no `error:0407008A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding` when CURLing into it!